# "& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)" w3c markup

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm using w3c markup validator. I get this error:

```
Line 169, Column 60: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=4">
```

If I use &amp instead of &, I can't pass values to next page. 
Someone please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: "If I use &amp instead of &, I can't pass values to next page." Not possible.

Comment: I tried with &amp. Failed to get values in next page

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Did you include the semi-colon after `&amp`? Your link should be

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=4">
```

Note that if you paste this url into the address bar of your browser it won't work - the browser converts the `&amp;` into `&` when you click the link in  the page.

Comment: Links with this format work when you paste them into browsers. I've tested with the latest versions of Windows Firefox, Chrome, and also IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE11; and they all work properly. Any references or tests pointing to such links not working?

Comment: @MarioAwad the browser will interpret any characters after the & as part of the parameter name, so rather than a parameter call 'view' you get one called 'amp;view' - see here for an example: http://httpbin.org/get?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=6&amp;Itemid=4

Answer (score 0):

The value of an href attribute should be url encoded, not html encoded:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content%26view=article%26id=6%26Itemid=4">
```